# SQLite erro: foreign key mismatch (fk incompativeis) ao tentar fazer um INSERT

Tags: android, sql, banco-de-dados, query, sqlite

Eu estou tentando criar uma **Entidade Associativa** (N:N) no SQLite como esta:

> [ Pet ---< VacinaPet >--- Vacina ]

E, aqui está código da minha Entidade Associativa

```
CREATE TABLE  VACINAPET (
        vp_data TEXT NOT NULL,
        vp_is_aplicada INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        fk_pet INTEGER,
        fk_vacina INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (fk_pet) REFERENCES pet (pet_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (fk_vacina) REFERENCES vacina (vacina_id),
        PRIMARY KEY (fk_pet, fk_vacina) 
);
```

O código da minha entidade Pet:

```
CREATE TABLE PET (
        pet_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        pet_nome TEXT NOT NULL,
        pet_genero INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        pet_foto_perfil TEXT,
        pet_peso INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        pet_dt_nasc TEXT,
        fk_tpanimal INTEGER,
        fk_raca INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (fk_tpanimal) REFERENCES TIPOANIMAL (tpanimal_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (fk_raca) REFERENCES RACA (raca_id)
);
```

E o codigo da minha entidade Vacina:

```
CREATE TABLE VACINA (
        vac_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        vac_validade TEXT NOT NULL,
        fk_tipo INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (fk_tipo) REFERENCES tipovacina (tpvac_id)
);
```

MAS, eu ganho esse erro aqui:

> foreign key mismatch - "VACINAPET" referencing "vacina": INSERT INTO
>   VACINAPET (vp_data, vp_is_aplicada, fk_pet, fk_vacina) VALUES
>   ('23/05/2018', 0, 1, 1);

Quando eu tento usar o seguinte comando de INSERT:

> INSERT INTO VACINAPET (vp_data, vp_is_aplicada, fk_pet, fk_vacina)
>   VALUES ('23/05/2018', 0, 1, 1);

O que pode estar errado?

OBSERVAÇÃO: Eu tenho dados nas tabelas **Pet** e **Vacina** , eles não estão vazios de dados

Comment: Poderia adicionar a estrutura das outras duas tabelas!

Comment: Editado @NayronMorais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está na referência que está fazendo na tabela de associação (VACINAPET)
da tabela VACINA, na tabela VACINAPET você indica como chave primária da tabela VACINA o campo **vacina_id**, no entanto, na tabela VACINA sua chave primária é nomeada de **vac_id**.

Comment: Vlw mano, era isso mesmo!